# itertools.count returning more than one item per count

Tags: python, python-itertools

Here is a pastebin of the full script: http://pastebin.com/TfAc8sYM

Unfortunately there's no way for others to test this in my specific use-case as the API is not public.

There are a series of URLs that are `http://example.com/api/users/get.ext?user=X`

I want to go through these one at a time counting up and executing code for each URL.

If I load the API in the browser the XML looks just fine. Likewise if I print the requests.text data in the terminal everything is working correctly.

However when I run the script I get multiple outputs for the same API URL. I can see this in my database and printed via the command line. The amount of repeated lines per user entry seems consistent each time the script runs but it is inconsistent from user to user. The data within the repeated entries is identical.

Am I approaching the counting wrong?

Here's a sample of the XML. It's from the Vanilla Forums API:http://pastebin.com/aR51ShTM

Comment: The counting looks good, but you can find that out by simply printing your `count` variable right after setting it.

Comment: Are you sure whatever API you're using isn't just providing multiple data items per request? Nothing in the code you've posted looks wrong, but we can't see much. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: I didn't understand what you want, but may be you need: "for i in range(100)" to iterate from http://example.com/api/users/get.ext?user=1 to http://example.com/api/users/get.ext?user=100 ?

Comment: @GerasimovMikhail `itertools.count` returns an infinite generator. So this will iterate just fine... until the end of time.

Comment: I updated the OP to give a more complete example of my script. I suspect maybe the problem has something to do with the nested `for` loops using ElementTree. I couldn't find a way to collect the data within the tags using ElementTree without the `for` loops. Only the tags themselves.